# Applying Solidfy Modifier throws a "Hide, mask and optimized display disabled" error

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, error

I'm on the latest version of Blender 2.8. I'm following a tutorial where you make a donut. When I apply the solidfy modifier on my icing mesh, I get a "Hide, mask and optimized display disabled" error on my subdivision modifier and most of my icing mesh disapears. I have copies of my meshes in case I need to go back after applying and each time I copy it over and apply the modifier, it errors out.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Blend files in the comments

Comment: Before modifier applied: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6598" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6598/)

Comment: After modifier applied: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6599" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6599/)